# Relationship between Laplace and Legendre transform

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

In statistical thermodynamics, the canonical, $Z(\beta)$, and microcanonical, $\Omega(E)$, partition functions are related by Laplace tranform.
$$
Z(\beta) = \int_0^\infty\text dE \ \Omega(E)\ \text e^{-\beta E}
$$
The thermodynamic variables corresponding to both ensembles are obtained as logarithm of their respective partition functions.
$$
S = k_B\ln[\Omega(E)] \qquad -\frac{F}{T} = k_B\ln[Z(\beta)]
$$

Now, the quantities $S$ and $-F/T$ are Legendre transforms of each other.

A logarithmic map on Laplace transform pairs gives a legendre transform pair. What is the underlying reason for this ? I have learnt from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420047/what-exactly-is-an-integral-kernel) that integral transforms are like basis transformation. Now with regards to this question, where does this interpretation take us ?

Comment: Almost 5 years later, do you have an answer for this? I have the same question but haven't found anything

Comment: Not really, except for some interesting articles given in the only answer here, I have not found anything like a holistic map.

Answer (score 3):

These papers will give you some answers: (https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/33-765/pdf/Legendre.pdf) and (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1147), the very clear (https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/classical-mechanics-versus-thermodynamics-part-1/) and, at a higher level (http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~rumin/recherche/entropy-POVM.pdf).

Comment: Of these references, only the second (https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147) sheds light on the question here, namely how to get from a Laplace transform to a Legendre transform.  It's discussed in the section called "The Route of Mathematics" on page 6, and it points out what the question here left out: we get the Legendre transform from the Laplace transform by taking a certain limit, and using a saddle point approximation.