# Integral kernel of the Legendre transform

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, statistical-mechanics, legendre-transformation

First of all, I'm not sure, but I think the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) can be seen as a linear operator between the functions on a normed space and the functions on its dual. (A functional analysis approach reference would be welcome)

If that's correct, and the following statement of wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) about integral transforms is also correct:

```
"and in fact if the kernel is allowed to be a generalized function then all linear operators are integral transforms (a properly formulated version of this statement is the Schwartz kernel theorem)."
```

Then, it is possible to associate an integral transform to the Legendre transform as an operator. My question then would be: What's the kernel of that integral transform which represents the Legendre transform?

This is all related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1902058/798070), where there seems to be a relation between the Laplace and the Legendre transform in the macroscopic limit. And I was hoping that the kernel I'm looking for is the same as in the Laplace transform in the limit (logarithms apart). That would be awesome.

I know that I'm not being rigorous about the spaces in which I'm working, but I don't have the knowledge to make this question more rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather long comment:

The Legendre transform is not an integral operator acting on $L_p$ spaces, but a transformation that acts on proper convex functions. To be more concrete, suppose $X$ is a topological linear space (think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for example), and let $X^*$ be its dual space (continuous linear functionals on $X$)

**Definition:** For any function $f:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, the function $f^*:X^*\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ given by
\begin{align}
f^*(v)=\sup_{x\in X}\big\{v(x)-f(x)\big\},\qquad v\in X^*\tag{1}\label{frenchel}
\end{align}
is the *Frenchel--Legendre* transform of $f$.

We have the following result:

> For any function $f:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$,
>
> 1. $f^*$ is convex on $X^*$.
> 2. *(Frenchel--Young inequality)* If $f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})=\emptyset$ and $\{f<\infty\}\neq\emptyset$,
>    \begin{align}
>        f(x)+f^*(v)\geq v(x),\qquad (x,v)\in X\times X^*.
>      \end{align}
> 3. Under the  $\sigma(X^*,X)$--topology on $X^*$, $f^*$ is lower semicontinuous and
>    $f^{**}(x):=(f^*)^*(x)\leq f(x)$.
> 4. *(Frenchel--Legendre duality)* Suppose that $X$ is locally convex. If $f$ is proper lower semicontinuous and convex, then $f^*$ is proper convex lower semicontinuous and
>    \begin{align}
>    f(x)=f^{**}(x)=\sup\{g(x): \text{g affine},\quad g(y)<f(y)\}.
>    \end{align}

To give a simple example that shows a connection to the Laplace transform, suppose $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$. Then The set
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Delta}:=\Big\{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n: \int e^{\theta\cdot x}\mu(dx)<\infty\Big\}
\end{align}
is a convex set and that the map
$\Lambda:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ given by
$\Lambda(\theta)=\log\Big(\int e^{\theta\cdot x}\mu(x)\Big)$ is proper, lower semicontinuous and convex with $\operatorname{dom}(\Lambda)=\mathbf{\Delta}$

Define
\begin{align}
\hat{\ell}(x)=\sup_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\theta\cdot x-\Lambda(\theta)\}
\end{align}

Notice that $\hat{\ell}$ is the Frenchel-Legendre transform of $\Lambda$ (here, $\Lambda(\theta):=\infty$ for all $\theta\notin\Delta$)

The relation between $\hat{\ell}$ and $\Lambda$ is given by

\begin{align}
\hat{\ell}(x)&=\sup_{\theta\in\mathbf{\Delta}}\Big(\theta\cdot x-\Lambda(\theta)\Big)\\
\Lambda(\theta)&=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\Big(\theta\cdot x-\hat{\ell}(x)\Big)
\end{align}

This follows from Frenchel-Legendre's duality.

---

**Comment:**

- In statistics, if $f_\theta(x)=e^{-\Lambda(\theta)}e^{x\cdot\theta}\mu(dx)$ defines an exponential type of distributions, $\ell(x,\theta)=\theta\cdot x-\Lambda(\theta)$ is the maximum likelihood and $\ell(x)$ the *super-maximal likelihood*. $\Lambda(\theta)$ is the *cumulant generating function*.
- There are other applications related to the study of Large deviations.

---

Comment: wow man, thank you very much. I think this is the answer I was looking for, although I'm afraid I would have to spend some time to understand it. Some references or book recommendations?

Comment: The Lengendre transform appears in many places: in Evans, *Partial Differentia Equations*, AMS it appears in the context fo PDEs; in Aliprantis, *Hitchthicker's guide to infinite dimensional analysis*, Springer, it appears in the context of functional and convex analysis; in Kallenberg, O., *Foundations of probability*, Springer, it appears in the context of large deviations.