# Why is it called Kernel?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, integral-equations, initial-value-problems

In the Fredholm/Volterra Integral equation, the function **K(x,t)** is called as **KERNEL**.
But why should we call it with a new name '*kernel*' rather than calling '*function*' Itself ?

Comment: Closely related, [What exactly is an integral kernel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420047/what-exactly-is-an-integral-kernel), on which a Comment makes the point that applying such an integral operator might involve "loss of information".  The word *kernel* is used in other contexts in mathematics to directly denote such a loss, through identifying what elements are mapped to zero.

Comment: [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (K)](http://jeff560.tripod.com/k.html) says the use in integral equations is older than, and apparently unrelated to, the use in algebra. It apparently comes from Fredholm's French "noyau", via Hilbert's translation to the German word "Kern".